# Is Harry Potter and the Cursed Child Canon?

Tags: harry-potter, the-cursed-child

I have heard some debate on this. Some people think it is, some do not. Does anyone know if JKR said herself if it is canon or not? The people who think it is not, is that just their opinion? They don't want to accept the way in which the characters and plots are portrayed? Also the play is obviously not apart of the novels so I'm confused. Any answers?

Comment: Sorry. Didn't know it was already asked. Should I delete it?

Comment: This is a duplicate of a duplicate! What magic is this?